# Can I use the jQuery form plugin to just display file upload progress and then submit form as usual (without ajax)?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, progress

I have a form with a text input field and a file upload.

I am also using the jQuery validation and jQuery Form Plugin (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) plugin

I want to show the upload progress (which I have working no problem) but once the upload is complete, I would like the form to submit as usual, rather than via ajax. Is this possible?

My code is as follows. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
        <form role="form" action="new_version.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="newVersion">
            <?php echo $session->form_errors(); ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="title" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['title']) ? htmlentities($_POST['title']) : ""; ?>" required />
                <br />
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">    
                        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo FILE_SIZE_LIMIT; ?>" />
                        <input name="original" type="file" id="file_upload" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p id="status"><p>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" style="display:none;">
                <div class="progress-bar"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%"></div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload version" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">Upload version</button>                 
        </form>
        <script>

            $('#newVersion').validate({
                rules: { 
                    'original': { 
                        required: true 
                    }
                }
            });

            var bar = $('.progress-bar');
            var status = $('#status');
            var successLink = 'project.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>';

            $(document).ready(function() { 
                var options = { 
                    data: { 
                        ajax: 1
                    },
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        var percentVal = '0%';
                        bar.width(percentVal);
                        bar.attr('aria-valuenow', 0);
                        $('.progress').show();
                    },
                    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                        bar.width(percentVal);
                        bar.attr('aria-valuenow', percentComplete);
                    },
                    success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, form) {
                        if(statusText == 'success') {
                            $(location).attr('href', 'project.php?id='+<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (responseText, statusText, xhr, form) {
                        alert("Oops... Looks like there has been a problem.");  
                    }

                };               
                // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
                $('#newVersion').ajaxForm(options); 
            });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP**:

> *"I would like the form to submit as usual, rather than via ajax. Is this possible?"*

It seems not...

[As per jQuery Form plugin documentation](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started):

> The jQuery Form Plugin allows you to easily and *unobtrusively* upgrade HTML forms ***to use AJAX***.

If you don't want to submit via ajax, maybe you shouldn't use an ajax plugin.

However, any JavaScript progress bar will not work in that case; because the instant one clicks the submit button, the page will redirect to the `action` URL, and the user will be left looking at a blank page until the server-side script processes the submission.  This is the problem `.ajax()` was designed to solve; it allows interaction with the server scritps without reloading or redirecting the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pull this off by doing something like this:

```
// AFTER VALIDATION SUCCESS

// copy old form into a new hidden form
$('form#newVersion').after('<form action="something.php" method="POST" id="new_form" style="display:none;">'+$('form#newVersion').html()+'</form>');

// remove file upload box so that file does not get saved twice
$('form#new_form [name="original"]').remove();

// submit new hidden form and user is none-the-wiser
$('form#new_form').submit();
```